# Cannot update 19.04. - No Release file and other errors

Tags: upgrade, updates, 19.04

I have been trying to update Ubuntu 19.04 to 20.04.

Having been directed to:
*"How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?"* I found the GUI Method most helpful.
(*despite not having a GUI ! That's a question for later*)

Despite making progress (I got a sort of "Welcome to Focal Fossa"),
Upgrade produced:
"*An upgrade from disco to focal is not supported by the tool*".

Trying to tackle that, I got:
"*Repository does not have a release file*"

Which is back to the Subject Title of this request for help.

I used to do DOS, so not completely noob to a command line - but I'm not familiar with Linux/Ubuntu/Terminal.

So a **step-by-step guide** would be MUCH appreciated.

Thanks very much.

***EDIT***
Having gone round in circles, (*trying to follow instructions that turned out to be incomplete or old*) I took the advice to re-install, from here:
https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/

It won't launch.

(*As the Backup programme (Deja ??) failed to work I saved the Home folder to a separate drive.*)

I saved the downloaded 20.04 to a new folder.
There was no obvious way to launch.
Restart did not launch or show 20.04.

Looking elsewhere, failure to load was attributed to Grub.
After Restart, pressing Shift fails to show Grub.

Trying to repair Grub, I get:
~bash: sudo/etc/default/grub: No such file or directory~

Is that why 20.04 is failing to launch ?

If Grub is unnecessary, how do I launch 20.04 from its folder ?

I had a look in the BIOS.
The first item in the launch list (of 3) had a long, imprecise reference to >Ubuntu< - but no version mentioned.

Thank you.

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 had a single upgrade path; to the next release which was Ubuntu 19.10.  There was no upgrade path to 20.04 EXCEPT via 19.10; however your path to 19.10 was *gone* the moment 19.10 reached EOL. You'd have to *hack* your system to force upgrade; which is *unsupported* and not QA tested, thus we can provide no real help, as issues will very much depend on what you have installed as you've missed your intended upgrade path. If it's a desktop system; I'd suggest performing a *upgrade* via a re-install (ie. use non-destructive re-install), however that's desktop only.

Comment: You're off-topic with 19.04 support; and inability to find repositories on *unsupported* releases IS EXPECTED, the main archive is *moved*, with mirrors *dropped* (along with 3rd parties whom can decide themselves what they do; *drop* being the norm). See https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/01/23/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-23-2020/ for 19.04's EOL; 19.10's was six months later (*releases are April & October or each six months*)  The best *official* guide would be https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: If you're asking about Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, I'll suggest starting a new question as the upgrade from 19.04 to 20.04 is *unsupported* and 19.04 questions are off-topic due to EOL status. I regularly use older desktop installs for support & achieve my upgrade via *non-destructive re-install*, eg. I have a *kinetic* (22.10) install that is EOL & don't need another *lunar* (23.04) so my *kinetic* install will become a *mantic* (23.10) via re-install when I have time.  My data files (music etc) & additional *manually installed* apps (music player etc) will auto-install as part of that re-install too

Comment: Your question though was without much specifics, ie. no mention of Desktop or Server which **does matter**. 19.04 was the last *i386* release thus what I mention isn't possible if that's your architecture; and the non-destructive re-install is intended only for desktops (*and is QA-tested only with non-3rd party; it can work with 3rd party but won't work too depending on how it was packaged*)  If you have questions about 20.04 though; I'll again suggest starting a new question.